# Fluent API com ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, fluent-api

Conforme [este tutorial](http://www.umbraworks.net/bl0g/rebuildall/2013/10/22/Moving_ASP_NET_Identity_model_into_another_assembly), transportei o Identity em uma *class library* para encapsular a regra de negócio do sistema. Contudo, todo o sistema está utilizando *Fluent API* para mapear as entidades e o Identity gera as tabelas através do *code first*.

Existe alguma contra indicação em realizar o mapeamento da classe `IdentityUser` manualmente? É possível realizar este processo normalmente ou existe alguma particularidade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Existe alguma contra indicação em realizar o mapeamento da classe `IdentityUser` manualmente?

O recomendado é que você mantenha o código no *Assembly* em separado o mais próximo possível do código original do *template* web. O ASP.NET Identity é bastante receptivo a customizações e é bastante acoplado ao Entity Framework, então em teoria usar *Fluent API* não é problema, pois você pode obter um resultado equivalente usando outra abordagem.

Apenas certifique-se de que nada ficou faltando ao trocar de abordagem.

> É possível realizar este processo normalmente ou existe alguma particularidade?

A princípio não existem particularidades. Apenas certifique-se [de instalar este pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin) [e este também](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework) no *Assembly* separado. Ali estão resolvidas todas as dependências para o funcionamento correto do ASP.NET Identity.

Outro cuidado é o de não remover as configurações originais do seu `Web.config`. Isto se deve ao fato de que, mesmo referenciando o *Assembly*, a configuração vai ser baseada no projeto web, e não em um arquivo `.config` colocado no *Assembly*.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar suas próprias classes customizadas com o Identity.

Basta implementar as interfaces:

- IUser
- IRole
- IUserStore
- IUserLoginStore
- IUserRoleStore
- IUserClaimStore
- IUserPasswordStore
- IUserSecurityStampStore

Dá uma trabalheira danada, mas basicamente você pode guardar as informações de autenticação do jeito que bem entender.

Aqui nós estamos usando MongoDB, por exemplo. Dá uma olhada no MongoDB.AspNet.Identity pra ter um exemplo completo de como customizar a persistência do Identity:

https://github.com/InspectorIT/MongoDB.AspNet.Identity